# Excel Macro - Error setting cell formula

Tags: vba, excel

I need to add a function in my worksheet using macros. I need to pass a variable to the Excel function since `myWorkbook` and `sheetName`, to which it will reference, are variable.

```
MyRange = Workbooks(myWorkbook).Sheets(sheetName).Range("H11:H32")

theFormula = "=SUM(" & MyRange & ")"

Range("B2").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = theFormula
```

I get error 13: `Type Mismatch`.

I am not an avid VBA programmer, and this is giving me a big headache. I tried defining `theFormula` as String but no hope.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the Range object to a string representation of the range, for example to set the formula to `=SUM($H$11:$H$32)` you would;

```
Dim MyRange As Range
set MyRange = Workbooks(myWorkbook).Sheets(sheetName).Range("H11:H32")

theFormula = "=SUM(" & MyRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ")"

Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = theFormula
```

Or if you dont want R1C1 notation you can;

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(H11:H32)"
```

Comment: That seeems to work but even if i am referencing a diferent workbook i have the desired range from the same workbook .. do you what may be wrong ?

Comment: Not sure I follow, you mean B2 is in a different book/sheet? If so change to `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Formula = "=SUM(" & MyRange.Address(External:=True) & ")"`

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub MakeSum(sBookName As String, sSheetName As String)

    Dim rMyRange As Range

    Set rMyRange = Workbooks(sBookName).Sheets(sSheetName).Range("H11:H32")

    If rMyRange.Parent.Parent.Name = ActiveWorkbook.Name Then
        With ActiveSheet
            'same sheet, so just use address
            If rMyRange.Parent.Name = .Name Then
                .Range("B2").Formula = "=SUM(" & rMyRange.Address & ")"
            Else
            'same workbook, different sheet, so prepend sheet name
            'single quotes prevent error when there's a space in the sheet name
                .Range("B2").Formula = "=SUM('" & rMyRange.Parent.Name & "'!" & rMyRange.Address & ")"
            End If
        End With
    Else
        'not the same workbook, use external address
        ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Formula = "=SUM(" & rMyRange.Address(, , , True) & ")"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Progragmatically this wont work - you are saying the cell formula should equal "=SUM(" & MyRange & ")"  - however when is this actually evaluated ?

does theFormula =SUM(" & MyRange & ")

work?

Comment: No, i already tried with that.. actually i want to edit the cell by pasting this as a string... all i need... if i do "=" & Range1 it works.. which is weird.. so when i add an excel function it will stop working...

Comment: This is wrong. `MyRange` is a variable and that line will evaluate to `=SUM([value of MyRange])` correctly. The other answers explain how to resolve this issue.